# Objective-C: volumeChanged wasn't called even add a Observer for AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{

    float volume = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] floatValue];
    //[self innerSetVolume:volume];
}
```

volumeChanged will not be called when I push the up/down hardware volume button on device.
somebody met the question before?

PS:my test device is iPod touch with iOS 4.3, not iPhone.

Comment: did you start the audio session with AudioSessionSetActive?

Comment: I think I didn't, How to do this?

Comment: `AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);`

Comment: @Shingo Yabuki I didn't know KOF characters were programming iOS these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to start up Audio Session Services in order for those notifications to fire.

Here's the documentation for the call -- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioSessionSetActive